# SSRS - Importing data from a CSV file to use as a data source on a report server

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am hoping that someone could help me with my problem. I am able to make a local connection to a csv file and import it and use the data within the report. One problem is when I put the report onto a report server. It can't access the file on the local machine.

Would anyone know of a way, possibly using ODBC, to allow the report on the server to view the CSV file on the local machine?

Comment: Could you import the CSV file into a table?  You could separate it into your own schema and call it as a datasource connection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use an ODBC connection to connect to a CSV file. You just need to point the ODBC connection at the folder the files are in:

```
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source="\\\\SERVER_NAME\\FOLDER_NAME\\SUB_FOLDER_NAME";Extended Properties="text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited"
```

(Note the double backslashes and header property HDR)

Then select from the filename in your query:

```
SELECT * FROM FILENAME.TXT
```